# Sending SWV ITM debug messages on STM32 Blue Pill via ST-LINK V2 clone

Tags: stm32

I have connected my STM32 Blue Pill (F103C8) to my PC via an ST-LINK V2. I'm unable to get debug messages on the micro to show in the IDE.

[image: ST-LINK V2]

Using STM32CubeIDE, I followed the steps on the ST tutorials and various YouTube videos, but I can't get a debug message to appear in the *SWV ITM Data Console*.

```
  ITM_SendChar('a');
  HAL_GPIO_TogglePin (GPIOC, GPIO_PIN_13);
  HAL_Delay (500);
```

Why doesn't the char 'a' show in the SWV ITM Data Console window?

Edit: Removed unrelated Arduino mention and highlighted in title that this is a clone product.

Comment: That's not an ST-Link V2. It's a clone. What wires you connected between the dongle and Blue Pill? If you did not connect UART pins, you won't get UART comms, and if you did not connect SWO, you won't see ITM/SVW comms either.

Comment: Yes, I answered my own question and came to the same conclusion.

Comment: OK, but wasn't the original problem not getting anything to COM port with Serial.println()? The Serial.println() sends to wherever it has been told to send, the STM32 does not itself send anything anywhere, it's the Arduino framework writing it somewhere, and if it is a UART, then you need to connect that to your PC. The ST-Link V2 pod does not have an UART (OK so the -ISOL version does).

Comment: Ah, I see the confusion. Perhaps I should have split my question into two parts. Once I realised that SWV ITM is how you'd do it over the ST-Link connection, UART seemed like it wasn't what I needed. I suppose I could remove the first part about Arduino, what do you think?

Comment: I dunno. Maybe you should make sure to mention in the question topic and body that this is on a clone product. No one would have this problem on a genuine ST-Link/V2 which will have a SWO pin so I think the question is misleading.

Comment: Thanks, initially I didn't know either products were clones. Very confusing.

Comment: Some Blue Pills even have clone MCUs on them. Marketing materials say they have STM32F103, but they might come with GD32F103, or GD32F103 marked as STM32F103.

Answer (score 1):

The "ST-LINK V2" (photo in the question) is not an official ST product that actually exists, despite the ST logo on some of them. The real version of this is made by ST and is called [ST-LINK/V2](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/st-link-v2.html) (with a slash before the V2).

[image: Real ST-LINK/V2]

The clone/fake "ST-LINK V2" commonly lacks a connection to PA10 (the SWO pin) on the pin header. There is a [tutorial to connect the SWO pin](https://lujji.github.io/blog/stlink-clone-trace/). This shows you how to add a bodge wire from PA10 to one of the pins on the header (after cutting the 5V trace).

[image: ST-LINK V2 clone mod]

After doing this mod, I was able to view my `ITM_SendChar` output in the SWV ITM window using the cheap ST-LINK V2 clone.

[image: Working SWV ITM output]

Instead of using cheap clones, most people recommend a real ST-LINK/V2 programmer, or a STM32 Nucleo/Discovery, which comes with a programmer built in.

Edit: Removed "official STM32 Blue Pill" (doesn't exist).

Comment: Official Blue Pill? Can you point to an official one? No Blue Pill I have ever seen can be recommended to anyone, for many reasons.

Comment: Thanks, fixed. The clone market creates so much confusion to newcomers like me.